# Will the google crawler use ajax _escaped_fragment_ format when a link redirects to an ajax link?

Tags: ajax, mod-rewrite, seo, googlebot, google-crawlers

I know I can do the reverse and have `server.com/#!/mystuff` be ajax-crawlable, but I want to know if the reverse is possible. If I have `server.com/mystuff` and that sends a redirect to `server.com/#!/mystuff`, will the google crawler then run that url through it's rename process so that it follows the redirect to `server.com/?escaped_fragment=mystuff`?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: true. any suggestions for a stackexchange community i might as this question on?

Answer (score 0):

According to webmaster tools, no [1].

> Question: When should I use _escaped_fragment_ and when should I use #! in my AJAX URLs?
>
> Your site should always use the #! syntax in all URLs that have adopted the AJAX crawling scheme. Googlebot will not follow hyperlinks in the _escaped_fragment_ format.

However the reality seems to be a bit different. I'm noticing googlebot following escaped format links.

[1] https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/faq

Comment: You can also add: <meta name="fragment" content="!"/> to the head if you don't want to use hashed fragments